# difference between failed and broken test

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I want to simply know the basic difference between "failed" test and "broken" test in nunit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about nUnit specifically but in general testing terminology,  the two are well defined.

A failing test is one which is well written and which has determined that the component being tested is broken. This usually happens when an assertion fails in the test case.

A broken test is a badly written test that fails because of an error in itself rather than in the module being tested. This can, for example, be a syntax error in the test.

Answer (score 1):

A failed test is a test which violated the asserts. A broken test could not be run because it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

A failed test is executed but the result is not what is expected.

A broken test cannot complete and return a result (no matter if the result is correct or incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

Failed test didn't pass - it means the test is correct but the tested code is not. The broken test usually can't be compiled or doesn't make sense because of significant change in the application.

Answer (score 0):

**Broken**: won't compile (or no longer makes sense)

**Failed**: Produced an incorrect result.

Comment: can i have just a simple example of both "failed" and "broken" tests

Comment: @user123: I just gave you one.

Answer (score 0):

Broken - for example during of the tests one locator wasn't found, or browser was crashed

Failed - failed on assert (in a place where u expect True or False)